# What exactly happens when I do buffer1.push_back(buffer2.front()) in C++?

Tags: c++, deque, push-back, double-free, invalid-pointer

Help me understand this.
Here is the context.

- I am writing a program in C++.
- I have 2 buffers (deque). Let's call    them buffer1 and buffer2;
- I have 2 threads: one thread is filling buffer1 with random values. The other one is copying the oldest buffer1 value to buffer2;
- I am using mutexes.

I want to copy the value inside the 1st position of buffer1 to the buffer2 and, in order to perform to do this, I write the following code line:

THREAD 1

```
   double a = 20.1;
   buffer1.push_back(a);
```

THREAD 2

```
buffer2.push_back(buffer1.front());
```

My question is:
**performing this, am I copying the value or passing the value by reference?**
I explain my question. I am having a random memory problem while running the program. I want to be sure if the source of the problem is here.

Thank you, everyone.

Comment: What's inside your containers? Ideally, you'd provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Was the documentation for [`front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/front) and[`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back) not clear on what happens?

Comment: @StoryTeller, you were right. It was a mistake commited here, but not in the program. Thank you! I edited the post.

Comment: @5gon12eder, the container has doubles.

Comment: @NathanOliver, perhaps I am having a problem to interpret the documentation (translation issues) :p it is not very clear, to me. I don't understand if i am copying (push_back) the reference given by front() or if I am copying the value given by the reference of front().

Comment: @AndyG, sorry for the lack of information in the original post. I am using mutexes already :/

Comment: If the deque contains native types like `double`, then the problem is not with the `deque` (or the underlying `vector`) but in how you use them. And if you have multiple thread then you *really* need to protect the containers (or container adapters) if you multiple threads can access them simultaneously. Read more about the [standard thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread), especially about its [mutual exclusion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread#Mutual_exclusion) facilities.

Comment: You cannot "push back a reference" because the deque (or its underlying container) does not contain references. You pass a reference to `push_back` but there its lifetime ends.

Answer (score 2):

To start lets take a look at the functions you're calling. The [`std::deque::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back) function takes its argument by reference, so no copying there. And [`std::deque::front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/front) returns a `reference` (or `const_reference`) so no copying there either.

Now lets take a look at the underlying container, which defaults to [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), and it's the same story with its [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) and [`front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) functions as for `std::deque`.

However if you look closer at the [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) reference, you will see that for the first overload the data needs to be [*CopyInsertable*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyInsertable), because that's really how the element inside the vector is initialized, by *copying* the object you "push back" (or *moving* if your compiler and the data type supports it).

So in the end, if you have a complex class you should follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), and if it does that then you should be alright and not have memory problem regarding this anyway. If you *do* follow the rules of three, five or zero, and still have problems, then the problem might be somewhere else. Try to use a memory debugger like e.g. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or similar. And if you have a multi-threaded application you need to protect resources that can be modified by multiple threads simultaneously (using e.g. mutexes or semaphores).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/front/) std::deque::front returns a reference to the first element:

> deque::front:
>
> Returns a reference to the first element in the deque container.

And according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/push_back/) deque::push_back copies (or moves) the content of the given element:

> deque::push_back:
>
> Adds a new element at the end of the deque container, after its
>   current last element. The content of val is copied (or moved) to the
>   new element.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your problem is somewhere else. Since you have the snippets in different threads, *their order may not be defined*. You can either end up with this sequence:

```
double a = 20.1;
buffer1.push_back(a);
buffer2.push_back(buffer1.front());
```

in which case everything goes ok, or with this sequence:

```
buffer2.push_back(buffer1.front());
double a = 20.1;
buffer1.push_back(a);
```

in which case you call `buffer1.front()` on an empty container. Copy constructor gets called on some random data and yields memory problems.